# getting error in Magento theme integration

Tags: magento2, php, error

I'm working on theme integration. I have download one theme and follow its documentation step that replaces AAP and pub folder and then runs this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. But when I tried it then getting error as attached in image. please help me to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: can you check in magento_new/app/bootstrap.php file available and are all directory available inside vendor directory ?

Comment: Not there is not available bootstrap file. But this app folder i have copied from which theme i have downloaded.

Comment: @AnsarHusain What can i do for that bootstrap.php?

Comment: can you first run "composer install" command ?

Comment: ok i can run composer install command. but once need to confirm that i have instal in magento_new direcoty/ correct? or need to install in app/ directory?

Comment: you need put theme code in app/code and theme file inside app/design/ folder

Comment: @AnsarHusain As per your suggestion, i have update composer but its showing error  `[ErrorException]
 file_put_contents(F:\xampp\htdocs\magento_new/app/etc/vendor_path.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
  directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102491/discussion-between-rk7002-and-ansar-husain).

Comment: Issue not resolved yet. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should reset file **magento_new/app/bootstrap.php** and all **the Magento core files**.